# Changing bootstrap grid for print media from col-xs to col-sm

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, media-queries

I have a webpage which when printed, needs to follow the `col-sm-*` grid instead of the `col-xs-*` grid. Is there a trivial way to achieve this? Can the width of the print preview page be changed, so that it fits all styles for `col-sm-*` rules?

Here's an example:

```js
window.print();
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <h1>Left column</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <h1>Right column</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what actually prints:

[image: Actual page that prints]

This is what I expect it to print:

[image: Expected print preview]

Comment: I guess it'll get the window size determined on call.

Comment: It doesn't. `col-xs-*` styles are followed even when printed from a large screen.

Comment: @JohnBupit Have you tried the solution I provided in my answer?

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the custom CSS for print that will override the `sm` in print layouts. This issue has been observed in bootstrap `version > 3.0`.

```
@media print {

.col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12 {
  float: left!important;
}
.col-sm-12 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-sm-11 {
  width: 91.66666666666666%;
}
.col-sm-10 {
  width: 83.33333333333334%;
}
.col-sm-9 {
  width: 75%;
}
.col-sm-8 {
  width: 66.66666666666666%;
}
.col-sm-7 {
  width: 58.333333333333336%;
}
.col-sm-6 {
  width: 50%;
}
.col-sm-5 {
  width: 41.66666666666667%;
}
.col-sm-4 {
  width: 33.33333333333333%;
}
.col-sm-3 {
  width: 25%;
}
.col-sm-2 {
  width: 16.666666666666664%;
}
.col-sm-1 {
  width: 8.333333333333332%;
}

}
```

[Here's the running snippet](http://www.bootply.com/js2PAvSiNC) of above sample with your code. **Click on FullScreen preview and then print it.**

Comment: Thanks for this :)